# Polling http endpoint using p-wait-for returning UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Expected condition to return a boolean

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, polling

I have the following code which is polling http endpoint using [p-wait-for](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-wait-for)

```
const pWaitFor = require('p-wait-for');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    simple: false,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/json1'
};
const waitOpts = {interval: 15};

(async () => {
    await pWaitFor(rp(options), waitOpts);
    console.log('done calling');
})();
```

I am getting error

```
(node:36125) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Expected condition to return a boolean
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.value (node_modules/p-wait-for/index.js:16:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
(node:36125) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:36125) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The intent is to keep polling https://httpbin.org/json1 endpoint every 15 seconds. It should keep running indefinitely because it returns 404 which request-promise turns into rejected promise.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by having the function being invoked return boolean (true/false)

```
const pWaitFor = require('p-wait-for');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    simple: false,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/json1'
};
const waitOpts = {interval: 1000};

const invokeApi = async () => {
    const res = await rp(options);
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

(async () => {
    await pWaitFor(invokeApi, waitOpts);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `p-wait-for` expects a `boolean` value back (as you found out).

A better version than your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225832/1392463) would handle any *unexpected* error too and also `4xx` and `5xx` status codes , see below:

```
const pWaitFor = require('p-wait-for');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  simple: false,
  resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  url: 'https://httpbin.org/json1'
};
const waitOpts = {interval: 1000};

const invokeApi = async () => {
  try {
  await rp(options);
  return true;
  } catch (_) {
    // non 200 http status
    return false
  }
};

(async () => {
  await pWaitFor(invokeApi, waitOpts);
})();
```